# Use regex to extract delimited decimals after a token in a multiline string

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a multiline string:

```
foo  1 2 3
 Values: 1 - 3 - 5.5 - 7
bar 4 5 6
```

The line I'm interested in (and no other line) contains the word `Values`, and I want to pull out subsequent decimal-numbers on that line.

I can do it in 2 stages:

```
In [1]: s = """foo 1 2 3
   ...:  Values: 1 - 3 - 5.5 - 7
   ...: bar 4, 5, 6"""

In [8]: re.findall(r'Values(.*)', s, re.M)
Out[8]: [': 1 - 3 - 5.5 - 7']

In [9]: re.findall(r'([\d\.]+)', _[0], re.M)
Out[9]: ['1', '3', '5.5', '7']
```

But is there a more rexegphonic way to do this?

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: For a language that uses PCRE regex engine, a possible solution would look like `(?m)(?:\G(?!^)|^Values:).*?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/2mWviH/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thankyou for this. Might you care to write it up as an answer with some exposition of how it's doing what it's doing? Even with the breakdown on regex101.com I find it hard to follow.

Comment: PS I've updated the question, I've extended the scope slightly (apologies)

Comment: Ok, so you can use the regex I shared with the PyPi regex module (`^` and `(?m)` before `Values:` is not required if it is not at the start of the line).